# Facebook Graph API: Conversion Dataset ID - Tracking Specs Offline Conversion

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

We are trying to attach the dataset ID from the Conversion API to the offline conversion tracking specs, but the ID in Ads Manager is different from the ID in the Conversion API.

For example, the following tracking specs:

`tracking_specs: { { "action.type": ["offline_conversion"], "dataset": ["1234567"] } }`

When we manually update the tracking specs in Ads Manager and then check the API, the dataset ID is different.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? If so, how did you resolve it?

Tried to find where the ID is coming from and we cannot find it.